# Cheerio / jQuery equivalent of Descendants.LastOrDefault (HTML Agility pack)

Tags: jquery, node.js, web-scraping, html-agility-pack, cheerio

I have web scraping code that is implemented in C# .NET Core 2 with the HTML Agility pack.

We ported most of our server over to node.js. The only remaining part is this web scraping bit. I'm currently trying to replicate this with Cheerio/jQuery, but i'm not too familiar with jQuery syntax.

What would be the equivalent of

```
DocumentNode.Descendants("table")
            .LastOrDefault(t => t.InnerHtml.Contains("<td align=\"center\">Match</td>"))
```

I tried doing:

```
$('table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody')
```

But this gives me a lot of tbodys still. I essentially want to grab the table's rows. The table I want should contain that td field.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Instead of adding the html I figured I paste the URL. This way we can just inspect the element. I basically want to grab the `Team Schedule` Table so I can parse through the roles and get their `Status`, `Match`, `Match Date` and the rest of the columns for that table.
https://www.ustanorcal.com/teaminfo.asp?id=82607

I was able to do this before with the snippet I added in my post above using the `Descendants("table").LastOrDefault()`, But i'm not sure how to do that with jQuery.

Comment: What [mcve] html are you working with, and what elements do you wish to retrieve with the selector?

Comment: It sounds like you want: $('td[align="center"]'). Note that this is just css so if you need to become familiar with it there's plenty of documentation.

Comment: I added an example above. Wouldn't that grab me all `td` elements that satisfy that? I would like the table and all the rows of it. Sorry for not pasting the example earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do those:

```
// team schedule rows:
$('table:has(b:contains("Team Schedule")) + table table tr')
// team roster rows:
$('table:has(b:contains("Team Roster")) + table table tr')
```

I think this is a lot cleaner than the HTML Agility stuff

Comment: Thanks! If you don't mind, can you explain that? I think I follow the `table:has(b:contains("Team Roster"))` part which is basically finding a table that has a `<b>` element that contains the text `Team Roster`. But what does the + table table tr part do? Is that saying get the table immediately placed after words that contains a tr?

Comment: I think that gets only `tr` which is the header row containing the labels `status` `match` and so on. If i wanted the rows underneath it, I would just use this right:
`$('table:has(b:contains("Team Schedule")) + table table')` which basically drops the final tr in your example

Comment: Ahh nevermind, I think I get it now. Your query was right. If I wanted to skip the first 3 rows would I just do a `.each()` and only add things when the ndx is 3?

Comment: Yay, I found something that worked: `:not(:first-child,:nth-child(2),:nth-child(3))`

Comment: Sorry, `+` is next sibling (of the first table) and skip 3 would be `nth-child(n+4)` - this is all just css by the way.

Comment: Ah okayThanks! I'll check out the css selectors reference. Just to confirm, `'table:has(b:contains("Team Roster")) + table table tr:not(:first-child,:nth-child(2),:nth-child(3)'`  is equivalent to `'table:has(b:contains("Team Roster")) + table table tr:nth-child(n+4)'` right?